# How to see content of the ebs volume that are in not attached to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

In my AWS account, there exists a collection of EBS volumes that are currently unattached to any running EC2 instances. Regrettably, I find myself uncertain about the data and contents residing within these EBS volumes, prompting me to seek an effective method to conduct a thorough audit and gain a clear understanding of their data.

To commence the audit process, I am seeking guidance on the optimal approach to assess the contents of these EBS volumes. As they are not currently mounted or associated with any instances, I am curious about the best course of action to explore their data.

Comment: Other than attach them to an EC2 instance and mount them?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EBS Volumes can only be accessed by attaching them to an Amazon EC2 instance.

Think of them as a USB Disk sitting in your drawer. To see what's on the disk, you need to plug it into a computer.